# Extend custom C# Akka actors using Akka F# idiomatic API (Akka.FSharp)

Tags: c#, f#, akka.net, akka.fsharp

I have a .NET library written in C#, containing a number of Akka actor classes (inheriting from Akka.ActorBase subclasses, like UntypedActor or ReceivActor). I would like to use this library (for an application or for extending it), using F#. Of course  I know that I can write OO code in F#, but what I would like to do is use Akka.FSharp idiomatic API.
Is this possible? Has anyone already done it? Some examples would be appreciated if available.